# c# Regex: find placeholders as substring

Tags: c#, regex

i have following string.

```
"hello [#NAME#]. nice to meet you. I heard about you via [#SOURCE#]."
```

in above text i have two place holders. NAME and SOURCE

i want to extract these sub string using Reg Ex.

what would be the reg ex pattern to find list of these place holders.

i tried

```
string pattern = @"\[#(\w+)#\]";
```

result

```
hello  
NAME 
. nice to meet you. I heard about you via  
SOURCE 
.
```

what i want is only

```
NAME
SOURCE
```

Sample code

```
string tex = "hello [#NAME#]. nice to meet you. I heard about you via [#SOURCE#]."; 

    string pattern = @"\[#(\w+)#\]";

    var sp = Regex.Split(tex, pattern);

    sp.Dump();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex is working correctly. That's, how `Regex.Split()` should behave (see [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx)). If what you said is really what you want, you can use something like:

```
var matches = from Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
              select match.Groups[1].Value;
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted to replace the placeholders using some rules (e.g. using a `Dictionary<string, string>`), then you could do:

```
Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => substitutions[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

Comment: what will be the pattern if this place holder contains space like [#FIRST NAME#]

Comment: Why would you use a regex for a simple string find/replace?

Comment: @jb, because there may be dozens possible placeholders, or you may not even know all of them.

Comment: @Mohsan, try `\[#([^#]+)#\]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
\[#([A-Z]+)#\]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^hello (.*?). nice to meet you. I heard about you via (.*?).$
```

Very simply, the `()` means you want to capture what's inside, the `.*?` is (what's known as) an "ungreedy" capture (capture as few characters as possible). and `.` means any character.

[demo of above](http://regexr.com?2ttrm)

Unless you're placeholds are always going to use `[#` prefix, and `#]` postfix, then see the other users' posts.

Comment: But the regex shouldn't be dependent on the string. What if he wanted to localize it?

Comment: @svick: I was going on the basis that the OP was using the `[#tag#]` as a way of symbolizing where content would appear in a string template (the string format itself would remain constant, but the content in those places would be altered [i.e. a log file])

Comment: hmm, you could be right. I don't *think* that's what OP wants, but I'm not sure, so I would remove the downvote now if I could.

Comment: @svick: No worries. The post (IMHO) was a little unclear and I felt it had that beginner-esque feel to it so I assumed go the simplest route. ;-)